# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined when serializing leaflet data with $.param()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I'd like to preface this: I'm very new to JavaScript. I am trying to post user location and map bounds with Leaflet and an AJAX call. In my event handler `stateUpdater.onLocationFound` the log statements print out the correct user coordinates and map bounds, however I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined` when trying to serialize these values with `$.param()`. I am using Leaflet v0.7.2 and jQuery 1.11.0.

```
var map;

$(document).ready(function() {
    map = new L.map('map').setView([41.52, -71.09], 11);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
    map.on('locationfound', stateUpdater.onLocationFound);

    stateUpdater.poll();
});

var stateUpdater = {
    errorSleepTime: 10000,

    poll: function() {
        map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 18});
    },

    onLocationFound: function(e) {
        //This log statement produces the correct output
        console.log(e.latlng.toString());
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        //As does this one
        console.log(bounds.toBBoxString())
        var args = {
            "map_ne": bounds.getNorthEast(),
            "map_sw": bounds.getSouthWest(),
            "user_coords": e.latLng
        };
        //Uncaught TypeError thrown here
        $.ajax({url: "/a/state/updates", type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            data: $.param(args),
            success: stateUpdater.onSuccess,
            error: stateUpdater.onError});
    },

    onSuccess: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        stateUpdater.errorSleepTime = 10000;
        window.setTimeout(stateUpdater.poll, 10000);
    },

    onError: function(response) {
        stateUpdater.errorSleepTime *= 2;
        console.log("Poll error; sleeping for", stateUpdater.errorSleepTime, "ms");
        window.setTimeout(stateUpdater.poll, stateUpdater.errorSleepTime);
    },
};
```

I have no hunches anymore as to what may be causing this, so I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Please see that your js files are loaded in proper order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like **bounds.getNorthEast()**, **bounds.getSouthWest()** and **e.latlng** return objects that contains some functions in addition to **lat,lng** coordinates, like **equal()** and **toString()** which prevents **$.param()** from performing serialization of your data correctly and this causes your error, here is a good way to get only what you need from those objects:

```
    var ll= $.extend({},{lat:e.latlng.lat, lng:e.latlng.lng}), 
        neBounds = bounds.getNorthEast(), 
        neBoundsLl = $.extend({},{lat:neBounds.lat, lng:neBounds.lng}),
        swBounds = bounds.getSouthWest(), 
        swBoundsLl = $.extend({},{lat:swBounds.lat, lng:swBounds.lng}),
        args = {
        "map_ne": neBoundsLl,
        "map_sw": swBoundsLl,
        "user_coords": ll
    };
```

I tested this code and it worked for me,the error disappeared and the ajax request was sended successfully.

Comment: man I couldnt find a solution for 2 hrs straight. thanks so much