# How to save google.maps.Data.MultiPolygon to geometry datatype column in postgres database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-maps, postgis, rgeo

I am a beginner in rails framework, so please pardon my naive question. I have a `google.maps.Data.MultiPolygon` object on my frontend which I want to save in my database. The table `searches` creates a new entry everytime a user searches, contains different columns out of which I have added another column with datatype `:geometry`, which will be updated when the user draws a polygon at a specific search. So we need to update a search entry in the database, for which I am using `put` call. I cannot send the whole `google.maps.Data.MultiPolygons` object on the put call, since `$.params()` is unable to serialise the object (this problem is the same which is faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317655/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-lat-of-undefined-when-serializing-lea)).

```
var polygons = new google.maps.Data.MultiPolygon([polygon]);
var search_params = $.param({search: $.extend(this.state.search, {user_id: Request.user_id, search_type: search_type})});
Request.put('searches/'+this.state.search['id'], search_params, function(){});

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined(…)
```

So, I would need to send an array of location objects. Is there a specific format in which this array of location object is directly converted to `geometry` object on the update function? Here is the update function which is called on search update in ruby:

```
def update
    search = Search.find(params[:id])
    if search.update_attributes(search_params)
      render :json => {:recent => search}, :status => 200
    else
      render :json => {:error => "Could not update search."}, :status => 422
    end
  end
```

And the search_params is:

```
def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(
        :name,
        :user_id,
        :q,
        :drawn_polygons #This is the column I want to be updated with geometry object
      )
    end
```

Would something like `:drawn_polygons => RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiPolygonImpl` work? If it does, what format of `:drawn_polygons` object do I need to provide?

**OR**

I need to take the `:drawn_polygons` as a list of coordinates, and change it to a `RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiPolygonImpl` inside the update function? If so, how to do it?

```
def update
    search = Search.find(params[:id])
    search_parameters = search_params
    drawn_polygons = JSON.parse(URI.decode(search_parameters[:drawn_polygons]))
    # Some code to change the search_params[:drawn_polygons] to geometry object, specifically RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiPolygonImpl
    search_parameters(:drawn_polygons) = drawn_polygons
    if search.update_attributes(search_parameters)
      render :json => {:recent => search}, :status => 200
    else
      render :json => {:error => "Could not update search."}, :status => 422
    end
  end
```